# How to fold by a tag a group of selected (neighbor) tags with XSLT1?

Tags: xslt, fold

I have a set of sequential nodes that must be enclosed into a new element. Example:

```
  <root>
    <c>cccc</c>
    <a gr="g1">aaaa</a>    <b gr="g1">1111</b>
    <a gr="g2">bbbb</a>   <b gr="g2">2222</b>
  </root>
```

that must be enclosed by `fold` tags, resulting (after XSLT) in:

```
  <root>
    <c>cccc</c>
    <fold><a gr="g1">aaaa</a>    <b gr="g1">1111</b></fold>
    <fold><a gr="g2">bbbb</a>   <b gr="g2">2222</b></fold>
  </root>
```

So, I have a "label for grouping" (`@gr`) but not imagine how to produce correct fold tags.

---

I am trying to use the clues of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13374401/287948), or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775595/grouping-nested-elements-in-xslt-1-0)...  But I have a "label for grouping", so I understand that my solution not needs the use of `key()` function.

My non-general solution is:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
       <root>
       <xsl:copy-of select="root/c"/>
       <fold><xsl:for-each select="//*[@gr='g1']">
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each></fold>

       <fold><xsl:for-each select="//*[@gr='g2']">
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each></fold>

       </root>
   </xsl:template>
```

I need a general solution (!), looping by all @gr and coping (identity) all context  that not have  @gr... perhaps using *identity transform*.

Another (future) problem is to do this recursively, with fold of foldings.

Comment: Are the `gr` values for each group always distinct within a `root`, and if not then if you have `<root><a gr="g1">a1</a><b gr="g1">b1</b>  <a gr="g2">a2</a><b gr="g2">b2</b>   <a gr="g1">a3</a><b gr="g1">b3</b></root>` should that give you three `fold` elements (a1/b1, a2/b2, a3/b3) or two (a1/b1/a3/b3, a2/b2)?

Comment: You can use the "two" hypothesis, but in my real problem, the @gr is a sequence that not reapeat, that is, if a sequence stoped it does not appear anymore (the next group will be g3, impossible g1 after g2).

Comment: OK, and is that example your complete XML document or do you have several different `root` elements that need to be "folded" individually?

Comment: I edited... And add "neighbor" to the question title. About "fold of folds" it is not a problem now, but I thing I will have this problem in the future.

Comment: [See similiar question-and-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1903906), and [more complex case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18312972/287948).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 the standard technique to handle this sort of thing is called Muenchian grouping, and involves the use of a *key* that defines how the nodes should be grouped and a trick using `generate-id` to extract just the first node in each group as a proxy for the group as a whole.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="elementsByGr" match="*[@gr]" use="@gr" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- match the first element with each @gr value -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@gr][generate-id() =
         generate-id(key('elementsByGr', @gr)[1])]" priority="2">
    <fold>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('elementsByGr', @gr)">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fold>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore subsequent ones in template matching, they're handled within
       the first element template -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@gr]" priority="1" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This achieves the grouping you're after, but just like your non-general solution it doesn't preserve the indentation and the whitespace text nodes between the `a` and `b` elements, i.e. it will give you

```
<root>
  <c>cccc</c>
  <fold>
    <a gr="g1">aaaa</a>
    <b gr="g1">1111</b>
  </fold>
  <fold>
    <a gr="g2">bbbb</a>
    <b gr="g2">2222</b>
  </fold>
</root>
```

---

Note that if you were able to use XSLT 2.0 then the whole thing becomes one `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@gr">
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- wrap each group in a fold -->
      <xsl:when test="@gr">
        <fold><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" /></fold>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- or just copy as-is for elements that don't have a @gr -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good explanation and elegant solution!

Comment: @PeterKrauss I've added a possible XSLT 2.0 solution too, for comparison.

Comment: Yes, with XSLT2 is so easy and intuitive... **I HATE XSLT1** (!!), but [LibXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) and PHP offers only XSLT1...

Comment: PS: I'm ahead you to my future issue at [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18312972/287948).